# Ionic 2 Running the function on another page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Once I open the application, I can see the number of products in the main screen.

But I can not update this number when I add every product in the cart.

I find the number of items in the cart in the TabsPage and I print it as needed.

I can not run the function that updates the number of products in the tabspage while adding a product cart on the product detail page.
How can I solve this problem?
Tabs Page Codes;

```js
sepetDetay(BELGEID){

    var header = new Headers();
    header.append("Accept","application/json");
    header.append("Content-Type","application/json");
    var base_url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var veri = JSON.stringify({
      ID : 0,
      BELGEID : BELGEID
    });

    this.http.post(base_url, veri, header).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{ this.SEPETSAYISI = data["Table"].length; });


}

<ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Sepet" [tabBadge]="SEPETSAYISI" tabIcon="ios-cart"></ion-tab>
```

[image: Show image]

Comment: Could you put some code ? I think .subscribe() could fit your needs

Comment: I added. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Events, this will help you to show the data.
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier with your add to cart function and tabset full code but there are the steps i may use:

1 - For the add to cart I advise you tu use "Observable" on fetching
2 - For the tabs you will be able to subscribe  to you observable

The changes on your cart will trigger your count update.

doc is here : https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: thank you, I analyzed the events and solved the problem